# Scanner throws no Line found exception after reading a input.txt

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a input text that is directed into the program as so.

```
Java Echo < input.txt

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Echo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Reads Text File

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
        // Reads User's Input
        System.out.println("Keyboard Input: ");
        if(sc.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

While Input will be read, `sc.nextLine` will return `null`.
How can I make it so `sc.nextLine()` reads from the user input instead of the file?

Result

```
$ java Echo < input.txt
A:Economy:name:W
Keyboard Input:
```

Keyboard Input is not read, but instead is just blank.
How can I make it so a user can type in input into the command line after?

Comment: You are redirecting `std.in` to a file.  What do you expect to happen after you reached the end?

Comment: To read from user input instead of file, **don't redirect input**. Give file name to program as argument, and let program open the file. and read it directly.

Comment: search for `java how to read from a file`

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the impossible. Input has been redirected, it will stay redirected. You'll have to supply the filename as an argument and run a different `Scanner` for it.

NB Controlling `nextLine()` with a test on `hasNext()` doesn't make sense either. It should be `hasNextLine()` as in your first read loop.

Comment: Is there anyway to redirect the input to user input after?

Comment: What part of my answer don't you understand?

Comment: @hhafeez Rubbish. You cannot undo an input redirection of `System.in`. Threads have exactly nothing to do with it. If you disagree, post that as an answer so we can vote on it.

Comment: @EJP I did not mean to undo redirection. I meant if he wants to read  in parallel then he can spawn another thread to read input. Or the simple solution would be instanitate another scanner object. you better mind your language though

Comment: @hhafeez Then you didn't make yourself clear, and you're not observing what it says in the question. He hasn't asked how to do anything in parallel: indeed he has specifically asked how to 'redirect the input to user *after*' above. I have already stated the 'simple solution' you mention, and I don't consider that the word 'rubbish' needs minding of any kind. In fact what your comment has to do with my answer remains a mystery.